# Change height of bootstrap form controls

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I am using Bootstrap input controls with label. My form consists of many input controls, that need to fit into available space. Even when I use "sm" group objects, they occupy lot of space (Especially height). I tried changing attributes in css for inputs like [type="text"] etc. The height of field is affected but not the label portion.

Answer (score 0):

Typing `[type="text"]` isn't going to affect the form labels. To change the label you need to type something like

```
form label
{
    /* your styling goes here */
}
```